# Sort objects in descending order when the < comparator is defined?

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, comparator

I have a class `A` and a `<` comparator. How can I use them to sort an array of `A` in **descending** order?

```
class A {
...
};

class LessA {
   bool operator()(const A& a1, const A& a2) const {
   ...
   }
}

vector<A> v;
sort(v.begin(), v.end(), ???);
```

I suppose I should replace the `???` with something based on `LessA`, but I can't figure out what should go in there. I thought of using a lambda function, but I was looking for something shorter.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Comment: A lambda is probably your best bet here.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to sort according to the relation defined by your `LessA` comparator, just pass an instance of `LessA` as the third argument (and, since you are using C++11, prefer the global `std::begin()` and `std::end()` functions):

```
std::sort(std::begin(a), std::end(a), LessA());
//                                    ^^^^^^^
```

Now if your `LessA()` expresses the `<` relation and you want to sort according to the opposite criterion, you could do:

```
std::sort(std::begin(a), std::end(a), 
    [] (A const& a1, A const& a2))
{
    return LessA()(a2, a1);
}
```

Another thing you could do is to let your custom comparator accept an argument that determines how it should perform the comparison:

```
class CompA {
    bool lessThan;
public:
    CompA(bool lessThan) : _lessThan(lessThan) { }
    bool operator()(const A& a1, const A& a2) const {
        if (_lessThan)
        {
            // return true iff a1 < a2;
        }
        else
        {
            // return true iff a1 > a2;
        }
    }
};
```

You could then use it this way to sort in ascending order:

```
std::sort(std::begin(a), std::end(a), CompA(true));
```

And this way to sort in descending order:

```
std::sort(std::begin(a), std::end(a), CompA(false));
```

Another possibility, given your original `LessA` comparator, is to use `std::bind` to swap the order of the arguments to your custom comparator:

```
LessA comp;
using namespace std::placeholders;
std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 
    std::bind(&LessA::operator(), comp, _2, _1));
```

Comment: Yes, but that would sort `v` in ascending order. I want it in descending order.

Comment: @PaulBaltescu Just flip what your comparison does then.

Comment: In terms of semantics, what is the difference between calling `v.begin()` and using `std::begin(v)`? Just curious.

Comment: @Magtheridon96: None, but `std::begin()` is more general (it works with C arrays as well)

Comment: I need the `LessA` comparator elsewhere and I hoped I could reuse it. Of course, I could implement a `GreaterA` comparator, but I was looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: @AndyProwl: Why use `!=`, when `a > b` is quivalent to `b < a`?

Comment: @Grizzly: You're absolutely right. Will have to edit, thank you

Comment: I would think e.g. `std::bind(LessA(), _2, _1)` is a more natural bind expression.

Answer (score 6):

Sort the range backwards:

```
vector<A> v;
sort(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), LessA());
```

[`rbegin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rbegin), and [`rend`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rend) give you  reverse iterators.

Encapsulate if it's too confusing:

```
void reverse_sort(vector<A>& v) {
    sort(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), LessA());    
}
```

Usage:

```
vector<A> v;
reverse_sort(v);
```

Comment: @Xeo What can I say, you have 30 upvotes for saying the opposite of me. 30 upvoters can't be wrong (c:

Comment: I didn't mean to use the upvotes as an argument, I just meant my answer as an extended explanation on why I don't like this version. Sorry if it seemed like the former.

Comment: @Xeo I appreciate that (c: I've encapsulated the function call, if that sweetens it at all.

Comment: I like this one. It's not more complex than special reverse comparison type, lambda or bind. Was it possible to use `std::greater` it would be better, but IMO here it is justified to use reverse range.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`std::greater`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) for the comparison functor. The default (`std::less`) will give you an ascending order; this will give you a descending order. (You'll need to add a `using namespace std::rel_ops;` ([link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/rel_ops/operator_cmp)) statement or explicitly define `operator>` as well.)

## Example

*Taken from [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort)*

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{
    std::array<int, 10> s = {5, 7, 4, 2, 8, 6, 1, 9, 0, 3}; 
 
    // sort using the default operator<
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    for (int a : s) {
        std::cout << a << " ";
    }   
    std::cout << '\n';
 
    // sort using a standard library compare function
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end(), std::greater<int>());
    for (int a : s) {
        std::cout << a << " ";
    }   
    std::cout << '\n';
 
    // sort using a custom functor
    struct {
        bool operator()(int a, int b)
        {   
            return a < b;
        }   
    } customLess;
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end(), customLess);
    for (int a : s) {
        std::cout << a << " ";
    }   
    std::cout << '\n';
 
    // sort using a lambda
    std::sort(s.begin(), s.end(), [](int a, int b) {
        return b < a;   
    });
    for (int a : s) {
        std::cout << a << " ";
    } 
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: How can I use `greater` in conjunction with objects of type `A`?

Comment: @PaulBaltescu You should overload the `operator<` for your class `A` and then everything will work automatically if you use `std::greater<A>`.

Comment: @PaulBaltescu I just made an edit. See the second paragraph in my answer for an alternative you could use.

Comment: @TimothyShields, `std::greater` uses `operator>`, it won't work with a class that only defines `operator<`, and the negation of less greater-or-equal, so is not a StrictWeakOrdering.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I assume this ( using rel_ops [link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/rel_ops/operator_cmp)) is standard? If not then yeah you have to explicitly define the `operator>` as well.

Comment: @TimothyShields The answer still contains the wrong assumption that `!(a<b) == (a>b)`.

Comment: @ChristianRau It does not make that assumption. (1) `sort` will work just fine if you give it a `<=` comparison instead of a `<` comparison. (2) If you use `std::rel_ops` like I suggested, it will actually build the "correct" `operator>` for you.

Comment: @TimothyShields *"sort will work just fine if you give it a <= comparison instead of a < comparison."* - The standard (in particular 25.4 [alg.sorting]) does not agree with you, though (even if your particular implementation, or even any reasonable implementation, does): *"For algorithms other than those described in 25.4.3 to work correctly, comp has to induce a strict weak ordering on the values."*. You may suggest `rel_ops` as much as you want, still you also suggest `std::binary_negate<LessA>` which is not a strict weak ordering.

Comment: @ChristianRau Removed that part - happy?

Comment: @TimothyShields Yes, of course! You sound like you're not happy with a non-incorrect answer?

Answer (score 0):

Given a function `lt(a, b)` that implements `a<b`, you can create a function that implements `a>=b` by returning `!lt(a, b)`. To implement `>`, you need to return `!lt(b, a) && !(lt(a,b) || lt(b,a))`.

`lt(a, b) || lt(b, a)` is equivalent to `a!=b`, so the above is equivalent to `a>=b && a!=b` which reduces to `a>b`.

However, you can probably get away with just `std::not2(LessA())`. That will sort with `>=` which will sort in descending order.

Answer (score -1):

Make the `()` operator of the `LessA` class return `!(a1 < a2)` and pass it in like this:

```
std::sort(v.begin(), v.end(), LessA());
```

Comment: Yes, but that would sort `v` in ascending order. I want it in descending order.

Comment: `!(a1 < a2)` will get you greater than, I think you want `(a2 < a1)` instead

Comment: I just negated the condition he told me is giving him backwards results and achieved that. Frankly, I can't tell which will yield correct results :p

Comment: @Magtheridon96 Generally speaking (there are exceptions), `!(a < b)` is equivalent to `a >= b`. You should negate the result of the hypothetical `a <=> b` operation: two items that previously compared as equal should continue to compare as equal (neither compares as less than the other).